# SQL Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I made one report(`A`) and in it I called three sub reports(`b`,`c`,`d`).
Now i call Main Report(`A`) and I export it to PDF.I have data only in two reports(`b`,`d`) but not in third report(`c`),so now I got some space between report `b` and report `d`.
I put condition in `b` report if data present then it displays otherwise not.
So now please tell me solution, how to remove space between two sub reports(`b`,`d`).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

reorder the reports to bdc otherwise,

try to put the reports in a rectangle together and allow it to shrink.